# How to get the index of particular view OR ViewGroup which is added to the ViewGroup(layout)

Tags: android

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="24dip"
    android:text="Add Notes" />
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="24dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="24dip" android:id="@+id/tlNotes"
    android:stretchColumns="0">
</TableLayout>

<Button android:id="@+id/bAddNoteLine"
    android:layout_marginLeft="24dip" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="ADD">
</Button>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/llIndex"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="21dip"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button android:id="@+id/bSaveSubjectiveNote"
        android:layout_width="192dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/bDiscardSubjectiveNote"
        android:layout_width="192dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dip" android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="Discard" />
</LinearLayout>
```

how to retrieve the index of linearLayout which has "llIndex" as id.
Thanks

Answer (score 112):

Very simple - call the indexOfChild function on the view's parent:

```
LinearLayout addNoteLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llAddNote);
int index = ((ViewGroup) addNoteLayout.getParent()).indexOfChild(addNoteLayout);
```

Answer (score -1):

When you create the XML, there is a file yourpackage.generated.R.java that is created with all the ids/drawables/etc in it.  So to reference it, import the generated R.java into your class, then do this (assuming you're in an Activity):

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_content);
LinearLayout addNoteLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llAddNote);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response...But actually i want index, Now in this example   the index of linearLayout which has "llIndex" as id is 3 .I want to read it through api.

Comment: Well I guess I am confused because what exactly do you want the index of?  Is llAddNote contained within another view, and you need to know which child # it is?